# For loop not working after Firebase Database Read in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have many articles in my firebase realtime database and I have named their node in a series of numbers.

I want to retrieve them using a `for-loop`. Before that I check how many articles are available and then run the FOR loop accordingly. But when I receive number of articles available the program stops and the for loop won't run.

Here is my code:

```
let numOfArticlesAvailable;

const numOfArticlesRef = firebase.database().ref('/articles/available-count');
numOfArticlesRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    console.log('Articles Available: ' + snapshot.val());
    numOfArticlesAvailable = snapshot.val();
    console.log(numOfArticlesAvailable);
})

for (let index = numOfArticlesAvailable; index >= 1; index--) {
    const articlesRef = firebase.database().ref(`/articles/${index}`);
    console.log(articlesRef);
    articlesRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
        const title = snapshot.val().title;
        const content = snapshot.val().content;
        const timestamp = snapshot.val().timestamp;

        console.log(`${title} has contents "${content}" and timestamp ${timestamp}`)
    })
}
```

The code log the correct value of articles available but the for-loop just won't start.

Comment: You need to run the loop under `numOfArticlesRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {})` callback

Comment: @AshishRanjan my code is going to have more further steps. Am I supposed to enclose all of it in that callback then?

Comment: Yeah, maybe enclose the logic under different functions and call those functions from under the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is not starting because `numOfArticlesRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {` is async function. This means that in the moment you for loop starts, value of `numOfArticlesRef` is either undefined or 0. or something like that. Try to do this:

```
let numOfArticlesAvailable;

const numOfArticlesRef = firebase.database().ref('/articles/available-count');
numOfArticlesRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    console.log('Articles Available: ' + snapshot.val());
    numOfArticlesAvailable = snapshot.val();
    console.log(numOfArticlesAvailable);
for (let index = numOfArticlesAvailable; index >= 1; index--) {
    const articlesRef = firebase.database().ref(`/articles/${index}`);
    console.log(articlesRef);
    articlesRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
        const title = snapshot.val().title;
        const content = snapshot.val().content;
        const timestamp = snapshot.val().timestamp;

        console.log(`${title} has contents "${content}" and timestamp ${timestamp}`)
    })
}

})
```